# Change TFS 2013 ActivityLog.xml location

Tags: tfs

Our build servers use the `D:` drive for workspaces and it's wiped every morning to avoid disk space problems. The problem with TFS 2013 is that it stores massive amounts of log (`ActivityLog.xml` files) in the `%temp%` directory of the user under which TFS is running and the `C:` drives are filling up quickly on our build machines.

Is there a way to tell TFS to put those log files elsewhere other than changing the value of the `%temp%` environment variable? Or is increasing the `C:` disk size the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can change the location but another alternative would be to schedule a task to delete the temp files periodically.

Here is another post where they are doing that.
[Large TFSUser\AppData\Local\Temp Directory on Build Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371702/large-tfsuser-appdata-local-temp-directory-on-build-machine)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `SetBuildPropertiesActivity`, Use SetBuildProperties to write key data points to the `IBuildDetail object`

`•LogLocation` (String): You can use the LogLocation property record the UNC file path to the folder where your build process puts the log file.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg265783.aspx

Comment: `LogLocation` has no effects on my builds. The note below `LogLocation` states _You probably will not need to use this property in your custom build process. This property is primarily intended for use by the UpgradeTemplate.xaml file to support legacy build processes._ so I guess that was expected.